# NullReferenceException ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nullreferenceexception

I'm having a bit of a problem to find out what's wrong with my code: I tried almost everything but this `@Model.Employee.Name` is always causing an error. I tried `(_employeeList != null)` in the `MockEmployeeRepository` but nothing fixed, also by hardcoding my `Id` to 0 the page is loading but it's not correct. If anyone could help me.....

Code link
https://github.com/umairr9/EmployeeManagment.git

Error message on /home/details

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> AspNetCore.Views_Home_Details.ExecuteAsync() in Details.cshtml
> +
> Name:@Model.Employee.Name
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Details - view:

```
@model HomeDetailsViewModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee  Details";
}
   
<h3>@Model.PageTitle</h3>
        
<div>
    Name:@Model.Employee.Name
</div>

<div>
    Email:@Model.Employee.Email
</div>

<div>
    Department:@Model.Employee.Department
</div>
        
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/CustomScript.js"></script>
}
```

`MockEmployeeRepository`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EmployeeManagment.Models
{
    public class MockEmployeeRepository : iEmployeeRepository
    {
        private List<Employee> _employeeList;

        public MockEmployeeRepository()
        {
            _employeeList = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee() {Id=1, Name = "Mary", Department = "HR", Email = "1234@gmail.com" },
                new Employee() {Id=2, Name = "Joe", Department = "Eng", Email = "qwrty@gmail.com" },
                new Employee() {Id=3, Name = "John", Department = "Admin", Email = "jpg123@gmail.com" }
            } ;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAllEmployee()
        {
            return _employeeList;
        }

        public Employee GetEmployee(int Id)
        {
            return _employeeList.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == Id);
        }
    }
}
```

`Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Scripts"))
    {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: true);    
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where you set @Model.Employee.Name?Can you share the data you passed to Details.cshtml?

Comment: What is the `HomeDetailsViewModels` ? And where do you actually return that view that you've showed us?

Comment: @YiyiYou i have my data in MockEmployeeRepository ..

Comment: you can check repository link for that file i added on git

Comment: i made that repository public you can have look into it and please let me know where im wrong @marc_s

Answer (score 0):

Try the url(use your port) like below :

```
http://localhost:36303/home/details?id=1
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: cool .. can you please tell me the reason why it is not working on http://localhost:36303/home/details since im calling it from id

Comment: im new to .net faced this nullreference so many times

Comment: @UmairKhan  It's because of  your route template. Besides, in your details action, `public ViewResult Details(int Id)`, here you should pass the id to the details action by the url. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-template-reference) to know more.